# Pygmo2: migration between islands in an archipelago during evolution

Tags: python, optimization, parallel-processing, pygmo

I'm trying to use the Python library *Pygmo2* (https://esa.github.io/pagmo2/index.html) to parallelize an optimization problem.

To my understanding, parallelization can be achieved with an *archipelago* of *islands* (in this case, *mp_island*).

As a minimal working example, one of the tutorials from the official site can serve: https://esa.github.io/pagmo2/docs/python/tutorials/using_archipelago.html

I extracted the code:

```
class toy_problem:
    def __init__(self, dim):
        self.dim = dim

    def fitness(self, x):
        return [sum(x), 1 - sum(x*x), - sum(x)]

    def gradient(self, x):
        return pg.estimate_gradient(lambda x: self.fitness(x), x)

    def get_nec(self):
        return 1

    def get_nic(self):
        return 1

    def get_bounds(self):
        return ([-1] * self.dim, [1] * self.dim)

    def get_name(self):
        return "A toy problem"

    def get_extra_info(self):
        return "\tDimensions: " + str(self.dim)

import pygmo as pg
a_cstrs_sa = pg.algorithm(pg.cstrs_self_adaptive(iters=1000))
p_toy = pg.problem(toy_problem(50))
p_toy.c_tol = [1e-4, 1e-4]
archi = pg.archipelago(n=32,algo=a_cstrs_sa, prob=p_toy, pop_size=70)

print(archi)
archi.evolve()
print(archi)
```

Looking at the documentation of the old version of the library (http://esa.github.io/pygmo/documentation/migration.html), migration between islands seems to be an essential feature of the island parallelization model.
Also, to my understanding, optimization algorithms like evolutionary algorithms could not work without it.

However, in the documentation of *Pygmo2*, I can nowhere find how to perform migration.

Is it happening automatically in an archipelago?

Does it depend on the selected algorithm?

Is it not yet implemented in *Pygmo2*?

Is the documentation on this yet missing or did I just not find it?

Can somebody enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The migration framework has not been fully ported from pagmo1 to pagmo2 yet. There is a long-standing PR open here:

https://github.com/esa/pagmo2/pull/102

We will complete the implementation of the migration framework in the next few months, hopefully by the beginning of the summer.

Answer (score 1):

pagmo2 is now implementing migration since v2.11, the PR has benn completed and merged into master. Almost all capabilities present in pagmo1.x are restored. We will still add more topologies in the future, but they can already be implemented manually. Refer to docs here: https://esa.github.io/pagmo2/docs/cpp/cpp_docs.html

Tutorial and example are missing and will be added in the near future (help is welcome)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the **`PyGMO2/pagmo`** documentation is confirming the **[migration](https://esa.github.io/pagmo2/docs/python/tutorials/using_archipelago.html?highlight=migration)** feature to be present.

> The **`archipelago`** class is the main parallelization engine of `pygmo`. It essentially is a container of **`island`** **able to** initiate **evolution** (optimization tasks) in each **`island`** asynchronously **while keeping track** of the results and **of the information exchange (*migration*)** between the tasks ...

With an exception of `thread_island`-s ( where some automated inference may take place and enforce 'em for thread-safe UDI-s ), all other **`island`** types - **`{ mp_island | ipyparallel_island }`**-s do create a GIL-independent form of a parallelism, yet the computing is performed via an async-operated **`.evolve()`** method

In original `PyGMO`, the **`archipelago`** class was auto `.__init__()`-ed with attribute `topology = unconnected()`, unless specified explicitly, as documented in **`PyGMO`**, having a tuple of call-interfaces for `archipelago.__init__()` method <sub>( showing just the matching one )</sub>:

```
 __init__( <PyGMO.algorithm> algo,
           <PyGMO.problem>   prob,
           <int>             n_isl,
           <int>             n_ind [, topology            = unconnected(),
                                      distribution_type   = point_to_point,
                                      migration_direction = destination
                                      ]
           )
```

But, adding that, one may redefine the default, so as to meet one's PyGMO evolutionary process preferences:

```
topo = topology.erdos_renyi( nodes = 100,
                             p     = 0.03
                             )              # Erdos-Renyi ( random ) topology
```

[image]

or
set a Clustered Barabási-Albert, with ageing vertices graph topology:

```
topo = topology.clustered_ba( m0    =    3,
                              m     =    3,
                              p     =    0.5,
                              a     = 1000,
                              nodes =    0
                              )            # clustered Barabasi-Albert,
   #                                       # with Ageing vertices topology
```

[image]

or:

```
topo = topology.watts_strogatz( nodes = 100,
                                p     =   0.1
                                )             # Watts-Strogatz ( circle
                                              #                + links ) topology
```

[image]

and finally, set it by assignment into the class-instance attribute:

```
archi = pg.archipelago( n        = 32,
                        algo     = a_cstrs_sa,
                        prob     = p_toy,
                        pop_size = 70
                        )              # constructs an archipelago
archi.topology = topo                  # sets the topology to the
#                                      # above selected, pre-defined <topo>
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer.
I also read this, but I still don't know if I actively have to do something for migration and what it's exactly doing in case it happens automatically.

Comment: Test it - by **`.evolve()`** the exactly same problem on an isolated **`island`**, resp. on the **`archipelago`** and compare quality of results achieved and time-to-run to see if the same problem + the same optimisation method they both used but **each on a different GMO-{ resources, "topology" }** to generate a result does indeed **match** in both the time & the same quality of result **or not.**